# Dataframe operation TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe where i want to calculate exp^-x.
X in this case is the value of another column from the same row in the dataframe.

For some resason i just end up with "TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'>"

Any ideas?

```
df  = pd.DataFrame([["Gothenburg", "2018-01-05", "jan", 1.5, 2.3, 107],
 ["Gothenburg", "2018-01-15", "jan", 1.3, 3.3, 96],
 ["Hallsberg", "2018-02-14", "feb", 2.2, 2.3, 168],
 ["Gothenburg", "2018-03-05", "mar", 1.5, 2.1, 96],
 ["Hallsberg", "2018-01-25", "jan", 2.5, 2.3, 87],
 ["Malmo", "2018-01-02", "jan", 1.6, 2.3, 104],
 ["Gothenburg", "2018-03-05", "mar", 1.9, 2.8, 102],
 ["Malmo", "2018-03-05", "mar", 0.7, 4.3, 151],
 ["Gothenburg", "2018-01-25", "jan", 1.7, 3.2, 45],
 ["Malmo", "2018-03-25", "mar", 1.0, 3.3, 98],
 ["Hallsberg", "2018-03-06", "mar", 3.7, 2.3, 142],
 ["Malmo", "2018-01-10", "jan", 1.0, 2.9, 112],
 ["Hallsberg", "2018-04-29", "apr", 2.7, 2.3, 100]])

df.columns = ['City', 'Date', 'Month', 'Mean1', 'Mean2', 'Mean3']

df["Val1"] = math.exp(-df["Mean1"])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have the line:

```
 df["Val1"] = math.exp(-df["Mean1"])
```

The python math standard library does not map the values of a list-like data structure (or Series in this case), it maps a single input (float or int) to another output as referenced here: [Python Standard Math docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

I would suggest you do a list comprehension to address this (i.e.)

```
df["Val1"] = [math.exp(-val) for val in df["Mean1"])
```

Additionally, you could use a python map or even use the numpy python package to accomplish what you had in mind with your initial code(I will leave this as an exercise for you to do. Start by looking at the numpy docs). Please take the time to look at the python docs and understand why the error message given to you is what it is.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will read in to the docs. I hope to learn more about dataframes and also numpys. I'm new to this but it seems very powerful!

Comment: Good to hear. You look like you're well on your way!